# CSS website changes div size once published

Tags: html, css, web

I'm working on my website, and have the main body div set to a certain width. But when I upload all my files to the web host the size of width shrinks, and no matter how I adjust the code for the div the width size stays the same(wrong size) on my published site, despite looking right when I just open the code in a browser.

I've tried Editing the code directly in the web host to see if I can even adjust the width at all. I've already tried deleting and re-uploading everything a few times.

Here's what I have on my **CSS** style sheet:

```
.body1{
    max-width: 1200px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: #fffdf8;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #f892c9;
}

<div class="body1" style="height: auto">
```

The width of 1200px is how big I want it to be, and it appears correctly when I open the html file in a browser. When I upload the code with a webhost the width is smaller, and even if I change it to a bigger number like 1500px it stays the small size.

EDIT: I'm publishing it with 000webhost.com. As far as I can tell there's no other CSS, only what I've uploaded for my page.

Comment: Try force refreshing using the refresh icon in your browser bar

Comment: try to `ctrl + 0` ;

Comment: where are you publishing it? is it hosted inside another website? are there any other css that overrides yours?

Comment: Yeah I already tried refreshing the page a million times first thing...lol

Comment: And yeah, ctrl + 0 doesn't change anything because I'm not zoomed in. All the other elements stay the size they're supposed to while the width of the div they're in shrinks. I can see images sticking out of the div because the div is the wrong size.

Comment: Just a thought, are you using a free plan?, doesn't 000webhost injects publicity into your page? if so, try to add `!important`, or change the class you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want the atributte "width" instead of "max-width"?
max-width its usefull when you want to resize the page with a specific width.

Check the Reference CSS anyway: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp

Comment: Using width didn't make a difference. Everything looks fine according to the reference CSS. I have no idea why it wouldn't be working, especially if it works the way I want when I just open the html in a browser...

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why exactly it wouldn't work in the first place, but I finnaly decided to just cut it out of the CSS style sheet and put it with the rest of my html the old fashioned way:

Now it works.